# How do I invoke non-GET/POST HTTP methods in Play?

Tags: rest, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a RESTful Play 2.0 application, and I'd like to call `DELETE /sessions` from a link in the browser.

How do I do this? Rails has a convention of using a `_method` query parameter for non-GET/POST requests, but Play's documents don't mention this.

Also, do I have to create a separate form or `XMLHttpRequest` in order to invoke the method from a link's `href` or is there something like Rails's `data-method` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not do that with common link.

[Cite from similar topic on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/Ttd7aFGCGpU):

> A link (A tag) is not intended to work with DELETE method. The semantic
>   of a link is to “link” to another resource, which can be retrieve
>   using a GET request. You can do DELETE requests in Ajax, or in form
>   using a POST method and containing an hidden input with name
>   “X-HTTP-Method-Override” and value “DELETE”.

What is that mean: you need use GET to delete the item:

in `conf/routes`:

```
GET   /delete/:itemId    controllers.Application.deleteItem(itemid : Long)
```

in your view:

```
<a href="@routes.Application.deleteItem(item.id)">Delete @item.name</a>
```

Or with AJAX call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url:"@routes.Application.actionToDeleteSomething()",
        type:"DELETE"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Seems correct. BUT, I'd say such particular client specific problem MUSTN'T be reflected in the server. Moreover the fact that the REST paradigm is broken now. So, what should be done is to not use an <a> tag but a <span> for instance that is rendered like a link. And keep DELETE in the route. OR at least, keep both GET and DELETE in the route, targetting the same controller

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I agree with Andy that adding a dedicated URL feels wrong. What I did instead was just leave the `DELETE` method in `routes.conf` and then, when the user clicks the link, invoke a JavaScript function that makes an Ajax call to the DELETE method with a success callback that sets document.location.href to the destination page. Still hacky, but it makes the client ugly and leaves REST intact.

Comment: You shouldn’t *delete* a resource on a `GET` http request.

Comment: @JulienRichard-Foy: So what instead ? form or ajax for each delete action?

Comment: Yes. `GET` actions should have no side effects.

Comment: But the question is, does Play support the X-HTTP-Method-Override for routes defined in it's routes file?